# Function references - Please enlighten!

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain why the two below are not equal?  I'm basically trying to figure out what's happening behind the scenes.  My understanding was that they'd both refer to the same function but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
var foo = function bar() {}

typeof foo //"function"
typeof bar //"function"

foo === bar //false
foo == bar //false
```

Comment: did you execute it in the order we see it?

Comment: Just FYI, if you want them to refer to the same function, you want something like `var foo = function(){}, bar = foo;` or `function bar(){}; var foo = bar`. Then if you compare them they will be equal.

Comment: You must be using IE8 or lower. It is a known bug where not only does `bar` leak into the enclosing variable scope, but a unique function object is created and assigned to `bar`. That's why `bar` is a function but `foo` is not equal to `bar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about you but my browsers return `undefined` for `typeof bar`

```
typeof bar //"undefined"
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/t8Czr/

---

The `bar` reference to the method is only available inside the method itself..

Comment: You're right.  I was reading an article and tested it in Firebug console and thought I got the result that I witnessed.  Unfortunately the exact code I executed is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

Bar is not defined.  Bar only exists within the scope of foo.

If you were to declare bar first then set foo equal to bar your results will be as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a named function expression because of the assignment to `foo`. In a named function expression, the name of the function is only available within the enclosing scope of the function itself, but not outside.

Outside it will simply be undefined.

```
var foo = function bar() { typeof bar; /* function */ };
bar; // undefined
```

Had the assignment to `foo` not been there, this would have been a function declaration and the identifier `bar` would have been available throughout the enclosing scope, even before the function was declared.

```
typeof bar; // function
function bar() {}
```

This is a [good article](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) to understand how named function expressions work and how they differ from function declarations.